# C# variable with jquery path referenced for jquery src file not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl( Urls.jquery) %>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

For importing jquery. The path is of the form 
`http://domain.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js`

In my developer tools console, the path is loaded perfectly, but when I try and run jquery it won't work. I'm kind of puzzled.

Thanks!

EDIT:

code i'm using to test it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 


        window.onload = function () {
            if (window.jQuery) {
                // jQuery is loaded  
                alert("Yeah!");
            } else {
                // jQuery is not loaded
                alert("Doesn't Work");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I also have another external .js file that says '$' is undefined in the developers console for chrome.

EDIT2:

It appears that this code actually works on Mozilla Firefox, but it does not work on Chrome or IE.

Comment: That looks fine.  What happens if you hard-code the URL instead?

Comment: What does "when I try and **run jQuery** it won't work" mean? If the library is loaded correctly, jQuery statements will work (provided they're embedded in a `document.ready(function(){});` - Also - are you honest using 1.3.2? Latest ver is 1.9.1!

Comment: Looks like you're missing types in your script tag in your window.onload block.  Intentional?

Comment: Forgot to add that, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Lilluda5 Have you placed a breakpoint on window.onload and then used watch to see if jQuery is loaded yet?  Seems like you may have a race condition of some sort here

Comment: I havne't tried that yet

Comment: Where do i go to set a breakpoint on window.onload

Comment: @Lilluda5 if using firebug, in the script window on the line that contains your test code window.onload = function ()

Comment: @DavidL Ok, there seems to be something extremely strange here. It appears that this is actually working in FF, but it is not working in Chrome, or IE. Note: I mean the actual question I asked, not the question about breakpoints.

Comment: @Lilluda5 Interesting...you said it was pulling it down but is it actually embedding the script in the page?  Perhaps look at page source in chrome to make sure it actually embedded.  Maybe chrome is having trouble with your resolve url code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by embed but the src tag on my javascript is fine. i.e. it looks like <script src="http://domain.net/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. I can also click on the link and it takes me to the correct page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, after basically giving up, i encountered the error today. I did not realize that one of my pages had a secure connection and one did not.

For instance

```
http://domain.net/page
```

would load jquery just fine, however the secure version, using https

```
https://domain.net/page
```

would not load jquery.

I am unsure of why this happens, but this is the problem. I'm going to mark this as the answer, but if any one else can provide insight on why this happens it would be great.

EDIT:

in my Urls file I had to add https:// to the front of the element, instead of http://, so everything works great now. Hopefully some one will see this later and resolve their problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code below seems to be working for me.  Maybe try it out?

Here's what I have for the server side code:

```
     public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string jQuery = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

And for the aspx page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl( jQuery ) %>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            if (window.jQuery) {
                // jQuery is loaded  
                alert("Yeah!");
            } else {
                // jQuery is not loaded
                alert("Doesn't Work");
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: good idea, but since jquery is not imported it causesa a syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried running that code in the JavaScript console after the whole page is loaded?.  If that works, then it's probably trying to execute your script script before the page is actually loaded.  Also, where is you're script tag in your page?  If it's at the top or in the head, try putting it at the bottom so that it runs after the page is loaded.

Comment: I tried moving it to the bottom and it still did not work. I made another edit to the post if you care to look at the @portlandrock

Comment: What does your server side C# for Urls.jquery look like?

Comment: it is just a string constant

Comment: Interesting...  I tried it and can't reproduce your problem.  I will edit my answer with what I have that seems to be working and you can give that a try.

Comment: I have the code in the App_code folder of my website, if that makes any difference.